# How do I set an exact float as the scaling factor for my y-axis limits on Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling

The number **1.67845714e-12** is an important result from my physics project. I want to plot graphs where the y-axis limit revolves around this result as a scaling factor.

In the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
import random 

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = 1.67845714e-12*random.random() - (4.20e-14)*x[i]

plt.ylim(float(-3*1.67845714e-12), float(3*1.67845714e-12)) #The important line 
plt.plot(x,y)
```

The resulting [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOA77.png) has a y-axis going from `-5*e-12` to `5*e-12` , instead of a y-axis going from `-3*1.67845714e-12` to `3*1.67845714e-12`

How can I get Matplotlib to display the step of `1.67845714e-12` on the top left corner of the graph with a scale of -3 to 3 displayed on the y axis like I intended? And if this is impossible because for example, the step is too long, can I give my step a nickname (such as "Result") to make this work?

I've tried using other commands like `ax.set_yticks()` ,  `ax=plt.gta()` or
`ax.set_ylim()` but nothing I've searched seems to work.

Comment: Could you care to elaborate or try to give a desire output example because I don't fully understand what you want. Also, you should know that if you set `y` limits from -3 to 3 you wont be able to see details of your plotted data.

Comment: Edited the post, hope it is more clear now!

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what you explained. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to answer based on what I understood you wanted to do. As I see it, you want to have a `y` axis from `-3*1.67845714e-12` up until `3*1.67845714e-12` but each step/tick would be of size `1.67845714e-12`.

Note I created a variable named `scalingFactor` to hold `1.67845714e-12`. I think this answers one of your questions. You can use it then instead of writing the whole number.

Ok, to generate the ticks so you can use `numpy.arange(inf, sup, step)` function. It returns evenly spaced values within a given interval `[inf;sup)`. So we are going to generate ticks from `-3*scalingFactor` up until `3*scalingFactor` using a `1.67845714e-12` step. You may notice in the code that `sup=4*scalingFactor`. It is because `numpy.arange()` exclude the upper limit of the interval.

To get the whole number on the axis and not rounded, you can force it to have 8 decimal places using `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.8e'))`. This function formats the labels for the ticks of the axis and it uses in this case this string  format `%.8e`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
import random 
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

scalingFactor = 1.67845714e-12

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = scalingFactor*random.random() - (4.20e-14)*x[i]

inf = -3*scalingFactor
sup = 4*scalingFactor

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.ylim(inf, sup)
plt.yticks(np.arange(inf, sup, scalingFactor))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.24) # Squash the plot from the left so the ticks labels can be seen
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.8e')) 
plt.show()
```

**Outputs**

[image: Output]

**EDIT:**
Well, I was actually, in fact, struggling with what you wanted cause I've never needed to do that. However I came up with a very ad-hoc solution for your problem based on what you needed cause it seems all of your data would be in that range and you wanted a scaling factor of `1.67845714e-12`.

There are formatter classes that can format tick values and handle offset value (the scale value on top left corner). So we can create a `ModScalarFormatter`that inherits from `ScalarFormatter` and override some functions to set manually the offset and ticks we want without letting `matplotlib` computing it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
import random 
import math
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

class ModScalarFormatter(mtick.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, useOffset=None, useMathText=None, useLocale=None):
        mtick.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self, useOffset, useMathText, useLocale)
        # Create the ticks we want
        self.ticks = [i for i in range(-3, 4)]

    def _set_offset(self, text):
        self.offset = text # Set the offset text we want

    def get_offset(self, txt=''):
        return self.offset # Return the offset value

    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        # The __call__ returns the tick on position `pos` from the
        # ticks we specified
        return self.ticks[pos]

x = np.arange(0,100)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

scalingFactor = 1.67845714e-12

for i in range(len(x)):
    y[i] = scalingFactor*random.random() - (4.20e-14)*x[i]

inf = -3*scalingFactor
sup = 3*scalingFactor

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(inf, sup, 7))

# Create and use a Custom Scalar Formatter Class
sf = ModScalarFormatter(useOffset=1.67845714e-12)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(sf)

plt.ylim(inf, sup)

plt.show()
```

**Outputs:**
[image: Ad-hoc solution]

**NOTE**: I am pretty sure there should be a more elegant way to achieve this, but this is my way of helping you with and ad-hoc solution for your specific problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to call `plt.ylim` **after** the call to `plt.plot`

Comment: Alternative y ticklabels: `plt.yticks(np.linspace(-3 * 1.67845714e-12, 3 * 1.67845714e-12, 7), [f'{i}*Result' for i in range(-3, 4)])`

Comment: @JohanC. Oops, you're right, already edited it. Also your other comments seems perfect also, although I was using `python3.5` and `f{}` does not work there. But it is a perfect valid approach. I would even say it is cleaner...

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to have the scaling factor displayed on the top left corner with only the numbers -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 displayed on the y-axis? Imitating the way matplotlib plots graphs by default?

Comment: To clarify, is it possible to display the step of 1.67845714e-12 on the top left corner of the graph with only the -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 scaling displayed on the y-axis? (this is how matplotlib plots by default)

Comment: As I thought there doesen't seem to be any obvious way to do this! Thanks again for your solution. I'll implement it until I find a more effective method, cheers.

Comment: @FunkyGammaRayBurst, I am glad it helped. What do you mean by obvious way?